# SqlDataReader HasRows=True but no data

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclient

I am connecting to an SQL Server 2012 database to query for a single value based on an ID. (It may be worth mentioning that this database is on a server on another continent from my development machine, and so latencies are quite high. Somewhere around 100ms).

The query appears to execute successfully. The `HasRows` property of the `SqlDataReader` object is set to true, so I try to use the value to assign a variable. When I run the program normally, I encounter an exception with message `'Given key was not present in the dictionary'`. If I stop the execution and inspect the `SqlDataReader` object, and enumerate the results. Firstly I am told `'enumeration yielded no results'` and then when I continue execution I get a different exception with the message `'invalid attempt to read when no data is present'`

Here is the code in question:

```
SqlConnection sql_conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
SqlCommand sql_cmd = new SqlCommand(String.Format("select ItemType from ItemTable where ItemID='{0}'", item_id), sql_conn);

Console.WriteLine(sql_cmd.CommandText);

sql_conn.Open();

SqlDataReader rdr = sql_cmd.ExecuteReader();

rdr.Read();

if (rdr.HasRows) //True
{
    item_type= TypesMap[rdr["ItemType"].ToString()]; //Either 'given key not found in dictionary' or 'invalid attempt to read when no data is present'
}
```

I have executed the SQL statement in SQL Server Management Studio and it is successful. I have tried hardcoding an ItemID into the statement in the C# code, and the same errors exist.

What more can I do to debug this? Everything appears to be okay, until I try to access the results of the query.

Comment: Not causing this issue **but**: I'd reverse the order, first use `HasRows` to check if there are any rows and then use `Read` to advance the reader to the next record.

Comment: The two error messages are caused by two totally different situations. What is the one that you receive with this code?

Comment: I would skip reader.HasRows and implement logic like
`if (reader.Read()) { item_type= TypesMap[rdr["ItemType"].ToString()]; }`

Comment: If you want get just one value, use rdr.ExecuteScalar().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to *debug*: it seems that the `TypesMap` *doesn't have* the key read from the database:

```
// Wrap IDisposable into using
using (SqlConnection sql_conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) {
  // Make SQL readable
  // Make SQL parametrized (and not formatted) when it's possible
  String sql = 
    @"select ItemType 
        from ItemTable 
       where ItemID = @prm_ItemId"; 

  // Wrap IDisposable into using
  using (SqlCommand sql_cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sql_conn)) {
    // I don't know ItemID's type that's why I've put AddWithValue 
    sql_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_ItemId", item_id);

    // Wrap IDisposable into using
    using (SqlDataReader rdr = sql_cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
      // rdr.HasRows is redundant - rdr.Read() returns true if record has been read
      if (rdr.Read()) {
        String key = Convert.ToString(rdr.GetValue(0));
        // Put break point here: what is the "key" value?
        item_type = TypesMap[key];
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

**Edit:** as Luke has mentioned in the comment, the cause of the error was that key comparison is expected to be *case insensitive*, so the amendment is to explain .Net how to compare keys:

```
var TypesMap = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

...
TypesMap.Add("aBc", "xyz"); 
String test = TypesMap["Abc"]; // return "xyz"; notice "aBc" and "Abc"
```

Comment: Thanks. It was unrelated to the Database query in the end. As ever it was just a stupid mistake, I needed to make the dictionary key all lowercase.

Comment: @Luke: a better choice is *not* to make keys lower case, but assign the appropriate *comparer*: `TypesMap = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`

Comment: I wasn't aware of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As Dmitry pointed out the 'given key not found...' is not a DB thing but a dictionary thing.
Below I've added a simple check to ensure the key is in the dictionary - if it is then we can assigned to item_type.

Also, if HasRows() isn't doing what you expect, try the following. It's the standard way I read from DB:

```
using (SqlDataReader results = sql_cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
{
    while (results.Read())
    {
        string Key = rdr["ItemType"].ToString();
        if (TypesMap.ContainsKey(Key))
            item_type = TypesMap[Key];       
    }
}
```

Comment: your standard practice is not THE standard practice. you should always call hasrows as standard practice.

Comment: @MaxAlexanderHanna Um, I didn't say and didn't imply it was standard practice. Just the way "I do it. Hence the word "I" and no mention of "standard practice".

Comment: if it doesn't have rows, theres a bigger problem and your attempt at "standardizing practice" is actually counter productive. no clue how you got two points for this answer.

Comment: @MaxAlexanderHanna lol, really. You pull up answer that's 3 years old (that's not even the accepted answer) and accuse me of being counter productive?

Answer (score 1):

I Converted:

```
dto.Id = (int)record["Id"];
```

To:

```
dto.Id = (int)record[0];
```

This worked for me.